# How can I get the value from SOAP Response

Tags: php, parsing, soap

I have the SOAP Response like,

```
<status qwe:type="ns1:AcceptedType" date="2015-03-04"/>
```

I need to get the type, date values in separate object by using PHP.
Is possible to do this using `getElementsByTagName`??

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to extract the node values using the below code, but there is no way I can think of to extract the attributes as XML nodes.

```
// get the last response from your response
$soapResponse= $client->__getLastResponse();

// create a new DOMDocument instance and load the returned content (exception block should be added here)
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($soapResponse);

// parse the XML for status nodes
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('status');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {

  // check if the required node attributes exist and output their values
  if ($node->hasAttribute('date') && $node->hasAttribute('type')) {
    $date= $node->getAttribute('date');
    $type= $node->getAttribute('type');
    print $date.'-'.$type.'<br />';
  }
}
```

If the nodes `date` and  `type` would have been child nodes of the `status` node, the following code may return the desired XML nodes:

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
      if ($child->nodeName == 'date') {
        $nodeDate= $child;
      } elseif ($child->nodeName == 'type') {
        $nodeType= $child;
      }
    }
  }

  // check if nodes have been created
  if (isset($nodeDate) && isset($nodeType)) {
    var_dump($nodeDate);
    var_dump($nodeType);
  }
```